# Magento 2-How to link image to category page through cms page?

Tags: magento2, category, magento2.3, url, cms-pages

I have a static page of `shop`. On this page there are different images. I want to link these images to the specific categories types.
For example i have an image of men's clothes. Now i have also a category of men's clothes. on clicking the image it should go to that category. As this page is made from the `admin>content>pages`. I am not able to get the base url or the link url.

Some one can help me in this regard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please use below code for link in static page

```
<a href="{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}<<YOUR CATEGORY URL KEY>>" target="_self"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/clothing.png"}}" alt="" width="IMGWIDTH" height="IMGHEIGHT" /></a>
```

OR

```
<a href="{{store url='YOUR CATEGORY URL KEY'}}" target="_self"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/clothing.png"}}" alt="" width="IMGWIDTH" height="IMGHEIGHT" /></a>
```

Comment: how this will link to the category ?

Comment: actually on the category when i click on categpry it opens a page of html. by writing clothing i am guessing you meant by the clothing category?

Comment: Yes exactly, use your category "URL key" in place of clothing

Comment: check my updated ans

Comment: i have got another solution what about this `{{store url='mypage.html'}}` mypage.html refers to the category page.

Comment: Yes that will be work fine, you can use anything, both will be working fine

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: I've added both options in my ans